# How to integrate R with Google Colab to run models (rmd files) create in Rmarkdown in the Google cloud?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

It really takes to much time to run my caret models (nnet, random forest and specially a svm model) in R. In order to speed it up, it seems that it could be worth to take advantage of the Google Colab cloud capabilities. However it is not clear for me how to conect my R laptop solution with Google Colab. I understand that it should be possible as well to import a rmd file in Google Colab, however I have not been able to find any guiding document to implement any of the mention procedures (R solution integration with Google Colab or rmd file export to Google Colab).

I woould appreciate a lot if anybody can provide me with any useful suggestion or link to any useful guide.